# Violation of unique key constraint that doesn't seem to exist

Tags: sql-server

I'm using C# with SQL Server. A method to insert a record is getting the exception

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint
>   'IX_PatientActuals_UPatientScheduleID'. Cannot insert duplicate key in
>   object 'dbo.PatientActuals'.

The stored procedure involved is a simple INSERT INTO.

I want to look at the constraint to see what exactly is going wrong. I've scripted the database and can't find the constraint mentioned. What am I missing?

The table definition is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PatientActuals](
    [PatientActualsID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PatientScheduleID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MachineSerialNumber] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [ActualPrimaryDosage] [float] NULL,
    [ActualSecondaryDosage] [float] NULL,
    [TreatmentDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [TreatmentTime] [int] NULL,
    [SecTreatmentTime] [int] NULL,
    [StatusCode] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [SecPartial] [bit] NULL,
    [Partial] [bit] NULL,
    [UVATreatmentTypeCode] [nvarchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [UVBTreatmentTypeCode] [nvarchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [Operator] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [DiagnosisCode] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [BillingCode] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [TreatmentPrepCode] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PatientActuals_PatientActualsID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PatientActualsID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Are there any linked servers involved in this scenario?  Perhaps the constraint exists on another server?

Comment: Have you tried scripting just the table?

Comment: You can highlight the table and schema and hit ALT+F1(usually by default in SSMS) to get the index names on the table.

Comment: I think you're missing a table definition.

Comment: No linked servers. I tried scripting the table, as noted. I added the table definition to the question. ALT+F1 didn't do anything when I highlighted the table in the Object Explorer panel; how do I highlight table & schema both?

Comment: Your problem is a unique constraint not an index.  (although of course there is an index behind it).  Take a look at sys.key_constraints.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Indexes will not get scripted when you script the database. You have to turn that on during the script. Even when scripting out a table, only primary keys get scripted, not alternate indexes.

Did you try expanding the table / indexes in SSMS to see if the index existed?

Or querying `sys.indexes`?

```
select * From sys.indexes where name = 'IX_PatientActuals_UPatientScheduleID'
```

Comment: There are a variety of indices listed that begin with IX_ but not the one in question.

Comment: @blearyeye: The index is there. If you cannot see it, you must be looking in the wrong place (Object Explorer connected to a different server instance than the one where the insert was executed, perhaps?).

Comment: The error was showing up on a different machine (running standalone). I got a fresh copy of the database in case something had changed. It hadn't except that for some reason they were using SQL Server 2008 R2 rather than plain 2008. I don't think that would have made a difference. Still don't see the index.